# Nesting If statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, mobile

I'm attempting to nest a radio button if statement within an if statement and im not sure where I put it.

I would like the function to do "if country's value is UK, and radio button is checked then.."

The code is as below.

```
$('#submit').click (function(){    

      $.mobile.navigate("#results-page")

      if ($("#country").val()==("UK"))  
      { 
           $( "#important1" ).text(UK.item1 ); 
           $( "#important2" ).text(UK.item2 );
           $( "#important3" ).text(UK.item3 );
      }

      if ($("#country").val()==("USA"))  
      { 
           $( "#important1" ).text(USA.item1 ); 
           $( "#important2" ).text(USA.item2 );
           $( "#important3" ).text(USA.item3 ); 
      }

      if ($("#country").val()==("France")) 
      { 
           $( "#important1" ).text(France.item1 ); 
           $( "#important2" ).text(France.item2 );
           $( "#important3" ).text(France.item3 );   
      }
  })
```

HTML (country)

```
<select name="country" id="country">
      <option value="UK">UK</option>
      <option value="USA">USA</option>
      <option value="France">France</option>
</select>
```

HTML (Type of holiday)
      
      Camping

```
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-2">Clubbing</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-3">Luxury</label>
```

Thankyou

Comment: Which radio button??? And then what? You should provide relevant HTML markup in question too

Comment: you should probably post the markup as well to provide some context

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Is `#country` your radiobutton?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting another if statement, add the condition to the existing if statement

```
//assuming radioButton is the id
if(($("#country").val()==("UK")) && ($("radioButton").val() == true))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it two ways:
1. putting it in the same if statement like below:

```
    if ( $("#country").val()==("UK") && $("#radiobutton").is(":checked")  {
        //do something
    }
```

2. or you can nest it in the if statement like below:

   ```
   if ( $("#country").val()==("UK"))  {
       //do something
       if ($("#radiobutton").is(":checked") {
           //do something because the radio button conditional is satisfied
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to see if it's checked:

```
   $('#radio_button').is(':checked')
```

You code would end up like:

```
$('#submit').click (function(){    
  $.mobile.navigate("#results-page")

  if ($("#country").val()==("UK") && $('#radio_button').is(':checked')))
   { 
       $( "#important1" ).text(UK.item1 ); 
       $( "#important2" ).text(UK.item2 );
       $( "#important3" ).text(UK.item3 );
   }

   if ($("#country").val()==("USA") && $('#radio_button').is(':checked')))
   { 
       $( "#important1" ).text(USA.item1 ); 
       $( "#important2" ).text(USA.item2 );
       $( "#important3" ).text(USA.item3 ); 
   }

    if ($("#country").val()==("France") && $('#radio_button').is(':checked')))
   { 
       $( "#important1" ).text(France.item1 ); 
       $( "#important2" ).text(France.item2 );
       $( "#important3" ).text(France.item3 );   
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var conutry = $("#country").val();

if ( country == "UK" && $("#radiobutton").is(":checked") )  {
    //do something
}
```